# At layered navigation need scroller in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

We have color option for attribute , it is display at left layered navigation.
i want to display only 10 , after that need scroler for remaining .
i see in other site .. 
for these have setting in admin side .
please suggest me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set fix height of this element.
and user to overflow:scroll

```
div.scroll {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks jaydip ,
I do that

.sidebar .block dd {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

But it is possible that if content is less then scroll is not appear[image]?

Comment: Hello Pratik, Welcome to Magento SE. It would be great if you avoid thanks comments posting as an answer. You are the Author of this Question and hence you have the full priviledge you for making a comment on any answer which is posting for this particular threat. So use the `comment` link which is available just below of the answer. This way the answerer get notified and hence he can follow up with you. Thanks.